# Custom photogallery not working correctly

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I've started creating this photo gallery, based on some code online and I've changed it a bit. When you click an image, it pops up and gets bigger. When you click the new big image, it goes to the next one in the gallery. When you click the "x", it should close, but it's not working. I've got it to work so you can click outside the image, and it will close though. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/MwgWoV/

Also I'm not sure the best way to make it so when you click an image, the image that was clicked pops up - right now always the first image pops up. I've thought adding a class "activeimg" and then styling it so only that image shows (as you can see I started in the code), but I'm kinda stuck.

Here's the jquery used for the ".close" links:

```
$('.close').click(function () {
$('#viewImage').add($('#faded')).fadeOut(function () {
    $('#viewImage').empty();
});
```

});

For the other part it might be easier to look at my codepen, it's a pretty small project.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use jQuery's eq method (https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to see which anchor was clicked, then change the image that pops up based on that.

Comment: This is a helpful link, thanks. I'm not sure how to set it up though, like in this example 

`$( "body" ).find( "div" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "blue" );`

What would the "2" be, if I don't know which image will be clicked? And once I know that, I'm not too sure how to make this image the one that's shown.. sorry I'm still a jquery rookie.

Comment: Well, the idea would be more like when they click, you do $(this).eq() and that will hand you the index of the anchor that was clicked. Then you would use that to decide which Image to pop up.